# how to check the result of the mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

I have a html form for the user to login to the website but i want to check if the following query retun true or false, I am using the PDO so I cant use the method `mysql_num_rows();`

```
<?php


$view = new stdClass();
$view->login = 'Homepage';
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
{
    $_firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $password= $_POST['password']; 
    $user = new UserPassword(); $user->getLogin($_firstName, $passWord);

}
require_once('Views/login.phtml');


  public function getLogin($userName,$passWord) {    

 $sqlQuerys = "SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `firstname`, `surename` FROM `sta177users` WHERE username = ' $userName' AND password = '$password'";
 echo $sqlQuerys;
 $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuerys);  
 $statement->execute();  
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to salt and hash your passwords and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually executing any query.  You are setting a variable, but not executing the code.

Also, **by building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. My site http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You execute the query and you fetch a row. If the result of that fetch is not empty, you have a valid user.

**Very important:** You need to salt and hash your passwords and use prepared statements to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
$query="SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `firstname`, `surename` FROM `sta177users` WHERE username = ' $_firstName' AND password = '$password'";
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchColumn();

if($rows == 1){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

Comment: That approach is very unsafe.  OP needs to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna do something like this:
<?php

```
function emptyQuery($db) // assume $db is your PDO object
{
    // your prepared sql statement with PDO::prepare()
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, 
        `username`, 
        `password`, 
        `firstname`, 
        `surename` 
    FROM 
        `sta177users` 
    WHERE 
        username = ' $_firstName' 
        AND password = '$password'
        ");
    // execute it with PDO::execute()
    $sql->execute();
    // return all the rows with PDO::fetchAll(), and then see if the array is empty().
    return empty($sql->fetchAll());
}
?>
```

This should implement your specification. You can use count() for a count, etc.

Of course, do not forsake the documentation:
https://www.php.net/pdo

Hope that helps!